# how to use property in for in to access data of the argument?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I tried to use the property name in for in loop to access the corresponding name of the req.body.id or req. body.title etc but it just ends up being undefined.
Can anyone tell me how is that and how to fix it? I even don't know how to describe this kind of question.

```
const HttpError = require('../models/http-error')
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const { v4 } = require('uuid');

const DUMMY_PLACES = [
  {
    id: 'p1',
    title: 'Empire State Building',
    description: 'One of the most famous sky scrapers in the world!',
    location: {
      lat: 40.7484474,
      lng: -73.9871516
    },
    address: '20 W 34th St, New York, NY 10001',
    creator: 'u1'
  }
];



const updatePlace = (req, res, next) => {
  const placeId = req.params.pid;
  // const { id, title, description, coordinates, address, creator } = req.body;
  const placeIndex = DUMMY_PLACES.findIndex(p=> p.id === placeId);
  const targetPlace = DUMMY_PLACES[placeIndex];
  console.log(req.body);
  for (const property in targetPlace) {
    console.log(req.body.property);
    if (targetPlace[property] !== req.body.property) {
      targetPlace[property] = req.body.property;
    };
  }; 
  res.status(204).json({place:targetPlace});
};

exports.getPlaceById = getPlaceById;
exports.getPlaceByUserId = getPlaceByUserId;
exports.createPlace = createPlace;
exports.updatePlace = updatePlace;
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `req.body[property]`?

Comment: yes! silly me, I tried useing req.boxy.[property] instead